# Android Alarm Manager not triggered when app is closed

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am trying to set an alarm manager. Here is what i do:

```
private static AlarmManager alarmManager;
private BroadcastReceiver alarmReceiver;
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    alarmReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
              Toast.makeText(context, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              WakeLocker.acquire(context);

        }
    };

    registerReceiver(alarmReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.alarm.wakemeup") );
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent("com.alarm.wakemeup"),0 );
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager)(this.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE ));
    SetAlarm(getApplicationContext());

}

 public void SetAlarm(Context context)
 {
     alarmManager.set( AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + 
             5000, alarmIntent );


 }
```

This works fine when i just lock the screen: The phone wakes up and toast is written on the screen after 5 seconds. But when i explicitly exit the application, the alarmmanager is not triggered. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: I think its due to its being registered in onCreate. Won't its instance be destroyed when you exit app? Register it in manifest.

Comment: Also keep one thing in mind your service will be destroy if your phone get restart. this should be test First. @bigO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25526267/android-alarm-manager-not-triggered-when-app-is-closed?noredirect=1#comment39851362_25526267), you will need to register the receiver in manifest file.

So that i will work even if your application is closed.

Your receiver instance is being destroyed when you exit app as its being created in `onCreate`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I also want To add one Thing that It will not triggered after restart of the phone.Again you need to start it Manually. Am I Wrong @Dhruti ?

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot you are right, alarms are wiped when phone restarts. I will try to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [static receiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) for this. You are registering the receiver into Activity, which is going to destroy when your app is not running. So how can that receiver listen your alarm.

So, register receiver into manifest. It will listen alarms even when your app is not running.

Answer (score 0):

This is for next phase Answer...

If you want to handle your service after restart You need to use WakefulIntent . What is that Will be cleared in this sample code as well as documentation.

[Github](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) Go with this repository will solve all your problem.

I used DEMO2 from this git.

Dhruti answer is perfect. **I Hope this will help too.**